# how to write this in latex form

Tags: math-mode, vector

[image]

I can't seem to find a code that would give me this format.

Answer (score 5):

The representation of a vector `$\vec{v}= \langle a,b,c \rangle$`

Answer (score 3):

Typing `\vec v=\langle a,b,c\rangle` will do.